# flatten a multi-directional array keys with delimiters recursively

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a multi-directional to an array of keys with delimiter with a recursive php function. Here is what i have so far. Not sure why its returning partial array.

```
$array = [
        'arr' => 1,
        'arr2' => [
            '_arr2' => 'test',
            '_arr2_2' => 'test 2',
            '_arr2_3' => 3,
            '_arr2_4' => [
                '__arr2' => 'tt',
                '__arr2_2' => 'ttww',
                'sub-sub-field' => [
                    'ww' => 1
                ]
            ],
            '_arr2_5' => [
                '__arr2_5' => 'some'
            ]
        ],
        'arr3' => 'test',
        'arr4' => null,
        'arr5' => [
            '_arr5' => [
                '___arr5' => 1
            ],
            '_arr5_1' => null
        ],
    ];

function print_array_reccur ($array, $str = '') 
{
    if (empty($array)) return null;

    $arr = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $val) 
    {
        if (is_array($val)) 
        {
            if ($str == '') 
            {
                $arr = print_array_reccur($val, $key);
            } 
            else 
            {
                $arr = print_array_reccur($val, $str . '/' . $key);
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            if ($str == '') 
            {
                $arr[$key] = $val;
            } 
            else 
            {
                $arr[$str . '/' . $key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

currently i am getting the below partial array output. Any idea as to why this is happening?

```
   Array
(
    [arr5/_arr5/___arr5] => 1
    [arr5/_arr5_1] => 
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell (and with the help of your test case - which always helps :), the problem is that when you were returning the new values from the sub array processing, this was overwriting the existing contents.  I've commented the two lines but just that I've used `+=` to add the new data to the existing array data...

```
function print_array_reccur ($array, $str = '')
{
    if (empty($array)) return null;

    $arr = [];

    foreach ($array as $key => $val)
    {
        if (is_array($val))
        {
            if ($str == '')
            {
                // Add new data into the existing array using +=
                $arr += print_array_reccur($val, $key);
            }
            else
            {
                // Add new data into the existing array using +=
                $arr += print_array_reccur($val, $str . '/' . $key);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ($str == '')
            {
                $arr[$key] = $val;
            }
            else
            {
                $arr[$str . '/' . $key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Hopefully the return value is what your after...

```
Array
(
    [arr] => 1
    [arr2/_arr2] => test
    [arr2/_arr2_2] => test 2
    [arr2/_arr2_3] => 3
    [arr2/_arr2_4/__arr2] => tt
    [arr2/_arr2_4/__arr2_2] => ttww
    [arr2/_arr2_4/sub-sub-field/ww] => 1
    [arr2/_arr2_5/__arr2_5] => some
    [arr3] => test
    [arr4] => 
    [arr5/_arr5/___arr5] => 1
    [arr5/_arr5_1] => 
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted. I also now realize my mistake. You are correct. Thanks for helping